# How can I add a simple plane on an "mgcViz" 3D plot?

Tags: r

I have the following code in R which draws a 3D plot

```
library(mgcViz)
library(rgl)
n <- 500
x <- rnorm(n); y <- rnorm(n); z <- rnorm(n)
ob <- (x-z)^2 + (y-z)^2 + rnorm(n)
b <- gam(ob ~ s(x, y, z))
b <- getViz(b)

plotRGL(sm(b, 1), fix = c("z" = 0), residuals = TRUE)
```

The here is the graph that I create:

[image]

How can I add a simple horizontal plane on z=5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `planes3d()` function from `rgl` to do that.  It uses the plane equation $a x + b y + c z + d = 0$, so `z=5` would have `a=0, b=0, c=1, d=-5`.  For example,

```r
library(mgcViz)
#> Loading required package: mgcv
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.8-40. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
#> Loading required package: qgam
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'GGally':
#>   method from   
#>   +.gg   ggplot2
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'mgcViz':
#>   method from  
#>   +.gg   GGally
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mgcViz'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     qqline, qqnorm, qqplot
library(rgl)
n <- 500
x <- rnorm(n); y <- rnorm(n); z <- rnorm(n)
ob <- (x-z)^2 + (y-z)^2 + rnorm(n)
b <- gam(ob ~ s(x, y, z))
b <- getViz(b)

plotRGL(sm(b, 1), fix = c("z" = 0), residuals = TRUE)
planes3d(0,0,1,-5, col = "gray")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that you can set the plane to be semi-transparent by setting an alpha value between 0 and 1, but `rgl` doesn't handle intersecting transparent objects very well, so it's unlikely to give nice results.

It also appears that `rgl` isn't working so well with `reprex`.  You shouldn't see the doubled axis labels.  This is fixed in the devel version available on Github.